# matrix elements prediction based on other matrices

Tags: matrix, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, factorization

Maybe here it is not a right place to make my question.

Anyway, I have the following matrices which `A` and `B` are sparse and `C` has no elements. how i can predict the entries in matrix `C`, regarding to matrices `A` and `B`?[image]

Comment: you can do `C = B' B`, `C = B' A B` or sample C completely randomly ... and many other things, without **exactly specifing what each one represents, there is no answer**.

Comment: Thanks @lejlot. The matirx A shows kind of prerequisite relation among books. for example book "ee" is the prerequisite for book "cc". Then you can see A as a directed graph which shows the prerequisite relation among books

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have some kind of similarities in all matrices. Then, you have similarities between books, which are based on co-occurrence of keywords and also on similarity between different keywords:

```
A = B C B^T.
```

Where A is your similarity matrix, B is matrix of keywords corresponding to books and C is a matrix of similarities between different keywords.

You have A matrix of size n_A, and rank no more than n_A. Then you can only recover C up to the same rank n_A, so you can assume 
C to have form

```
C = V^T V.
```

Then, you can easily restore C, by doing eigendecomposition of A.
On one hand, you have

```
A = U D U^T,
```

on the other hand, you have

```
A = B^T C B.
```

Comparing those two, you have

```
B V^T = U D^{1/2},
```

because D is diagonal (hopefully A don't have complex eigenvalues, though).

The equation above could be solved for V with minimum squares.

All those solvers you need for this are implemented in all major programming languages, for example, in python it is numpy library.

Comment: Thanks @Moonwalker. Great explanation. I just could not get this formula "B V^T = U D^{1/2}," would you make it more clear, please

Comment: A = B C B^T, C = V^T V => A = B V^T V B^T;
on the other hand A = U D U^T, hence B V^T V B^T = U D U^T, =>
B V^T = U \sqrt{D}

Comment: Sorry @Moonwalker for asking many questions. But let me put my question in another way. What are the V and V^T (did you get them by matrix factorization?) . in the final equation  " B V^T = U \sqrt{D} " what will happen to the V B^T and U^T.  Also, How we conclude  C from the last fomula which is " B V^T = U D^{1/2} " and finally what are the operation among matrices (is it Inner or outter matrix product)? Sorry again for asking many questions

Comment: @EsterSilva we assumed C had a form $C = V^T V$. In the final equation we've used symmetry, namely if matrix X = Y^T Y and the same X = Z^T Z, then Y = Z.
From the last formula, you need to solve B V^T = U D^{1/2} for V and then reconstruct C = V^T V

Comment: @EsterSilva If you are going to continue with this line of work, you should really check some course on linear algebra.

Comment: I think Now I got your idea @Moonwalker. Thanks alot . Was completely helpful